# Gradle - Copy jars of all changed modules in a multi-module project build

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-module build with approx 100 modules. Is there a way to create jar files for only the changed modules and copy them to somewhere?

The task should be a standalone task without modifying existing jar tasks

Comment: Do you want all JAR files in the end but only recreate the ones where parts changed or do you want a directory containing only the JAR files that changed for every build?

Comment: only those which changed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all your task inputs and outputs setup correctly, gradle supports up to date checking and task skipping out of the box. See [up to date checks (aka incremental build)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks)

For the copying, you could use a [Sync](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Sync.html) task which will only copy (or delete) jars that are different from the target directory.

Eg

```
task syncJars(type: Sync) {
    allprojects { p ->
        from p.tasks.withType(Jar)
    }
    into 'path/to/target/dir' 
}
```

Comment: It should be possible to just use `from p.tasks.withType(Jar)` as this will be evaluated via `project.files(...)`, which does automatically register the task dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried it. I added that task to the root project. When I run it it cannot resolve the dependencies between the subprojects for some reason. It says ':subprojectB:compileJava' compilation fails. But when I run that command in the commandline it works without any issues. In my subprojectB i have a compile project(':subA') and that cannot be resolved. Stange..

Comment: Hmm... guessing there's something screwy with the DAG. Try adding `evaluationDependsOn(':subA')` to subprojectB

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming all your modules are simple `java` modules, all your modules will have a `jar` task (of type `Jar`) that build the JAR file of the respective module. Each `jar` task will only be executed, if the contents changed in any way (e.g. new files were compiled), thanks to Gradle incremental build feature.

You can simply add a `doLast` closure to each of these tasks, which copies the created file to your directory, because the closure will only be executed if and only if the task was executed:

Example for a single task:

```
jar {
    doLast {
        project.copy {
            from archivePath
            into 'path/to/my/location'
        }
    }
}
```

If this works for a single module, we can try a similar approach as what @lance-java did:

```
allprojects { project ->
    project.tasks.withType(Jar).all { jar ->
        jar.doLast {
            project.copy {
                from jar.archivePath
                into 'path/to/my/location'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do want to have a specific task for it. The regular jar task should't be modified. lance-java's approach could work but I have a strange dependency issue here. I'm checking if that is related to some other circumstance

Comment: You should add these kind of requirements into your question.